# Why doesn't this page show properly in IE 7?

Tags: html

This is a simplified Chinese page, link:
http://www.vanillafactory.com/clients/womensclinic/www/sc/resources/weekbyweek.html

You'll discover that the page is blank when it renders in IE7 (FF, Chrome are fine).

However, if you download this page on your desktop and then remove the title tag, then the page works fine again.

What's the problem of this page? The title tag or elsewhere?

Comment: Works fine in IE8. Try moving the title tag below the meta tag with content type.

Comment: I find out what's the problem. My language encoding for this page is set to GB2312 by IE while the page should be read in utf-8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the encoding problem of different browser.

changing the encoding to UTF8 solves the problem.

Answer (score 2):

It works fine for me with IE 7.

Only thing is that the title tag shows up as a line of boxes.

This error is probably something to do with the security settings in your browser. Since it works from a local disk but not from the Internet.

Answer (score 1):

It works fine for me in IE7. The blocks in the title tag go away when you use the ENG tab at the top of the page. I believe that the problem lies with the Chinese language not being displayed properly in the title tag.